# Using mysql_fetch_array(); for prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

```
     if ($q -> num_rows == 1) {
            $q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE accounts SET logcount = '0' WHERE email = ?");
            $q -> bind_param('s', ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));
                        $q -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $q -> execute();
            echo 'Congratulations ' . $q['username'] . ' your account is now active!';
        }
```

How come when using $q['username'] it doesn't fetch the row username?

I am new to using prepared statements please forgive me :D!

Thanks.

Comment: You are not SELECTing anything. Where would you expect the user name to come from? Also, I don't see a "fetch array" instrcution in your code?

Comment: Hmmm I am still very new to this, I apologise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if ($q -> num_rows == 1) {
        $q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE ...");
```

You are overwriting your `$q` variable which presumably held the result of a `SELECT` (guessing).

Use a different variable for the `UPDATE` part.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing an `UPDATE` statement. To retrieve data you should use a `SELECT` statements. `UPDATE` statements returns only true or false; also mysql function `fetch_array()` should trow an error if you are trying to fetch a `non result`.

Since you code is starting with `if ($q -> num_rows == 1) {`, I think that `$q -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` is referring to a previous query. To separate and do not overwrite the two queries you should execute this code instead:

```
if ($q -> num_rows == 1) {
    $q2 = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE accounts SET logcount = '0' WHERE email = ?");
    $q2 -> bind_param('s', ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));
        $q -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $q2 -> execute();
    echo 'Congratulations ' . $q['username'] . ' your account is now active!';
}
```

References:

- [UPDATE statements](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)
- [SELECT statements](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp)